# confusion about while drawing string

Tags: c#

I have drawn a matrice on panel control.What i want to do is to draw some text inside theese rectangles.The problem is I that I cant make it bigger theese string .even I cant read .

```
void drawMatrix(Graphics g)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown2.Value; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numericUpDown1.Value; j++)
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(
                new Pen(Color.Black), 
                new Rectangle((50 * i) + 40, (50 * j) + 40, 40, 40));

            g.DrawString(
                "some text", 
                new Font("verdana", 3), 
                Brushes.Black, 
                new RectangleF((50 * i) + 41, (50 * j) + 41, 111, 111));
        }
    }
    g.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you want to use MeasureString and then draw a rectangle around it based on the returned dimensions. Really, put more effort in describing the problem. Edit: ah, you are refering to the font-size -> `new Font([fontfamily], [size]);` is all you need..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing the font size.

```
new Font("verdana", 12)
```

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8882dhsk(v=vs.110).aspx) the constructor is:

```
public Font(
    FontFamily family,
    float emSize
)
```

Comment: @ALACK Please do a little more research next time - StackOverflow is not a replacement for MSDN and Google :). Best of luck with your programming ventures!